# E-mail sent from mobile version of Zimbra is marked as Spam

Tags: spam, spamassassin, zimbra

yesterday I sent an e-mail from my company e-mail account to another company account, using Zimbra webclient on my smartphone. Unfortunately it was marked as SPAM, so I got task to find out why.

Here is header of the message:

```
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Score: 10.803
X-Spam-Level: **********
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=10.803 tagged_above=-10 required=6.6
tests=[BAYES_20=-0.001, HELO_NO_DOMAIN=0.001,
RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET=3, RCVD_IN_BRBL_LASTEXT=3, RCVD_IN_PSBL=2.7,
RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL=1.31, RDNS_NONE=0.793] autolearn=no
```

Every "significant" rule is connected with presence on particular blacklist, as SpamAssassin's wiki informs. I have checked all of them and our company server is not listed anywhere.

About rDNS - we have it.

Today I've tried to reproduce problem. I sent similar mail from my smartphone and I below is what I got:

```
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: 3.294
X-Spam-Level: ***
X-Spam-Status: No, score=3.294 tagged_above=-10 required=6.6
tests=[BAYES_05=-0.5, HELO_NO_DOMAIN=0.001, RCVD_IN_BRBL_LASTEXT=3,
RDNS_NONE=0.793] autolearn=no
```

Only two rules stayed: rDNS and Barracuda Reputation Block List.

As I mentioned: rDNS is set up correctly. Query BRBL again returns:

```
Host *.b.barracudacentral.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

which is good result, as far as I read.

When sending e-mail from webclient on PC or from Thunderbird, SPAM header looks like:

```
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: -2.9
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.9 tagged_above=-10 required=6.6
tests=[ALL_TRUSTED=-1, BAYES_00=-1.9] autolearn=ham
```

Our configuration:
Zimbra 7.1 (yes, I know it's old, it'll be migrated soon) on Ubuntu.

I can't figure it out. If you need more information, I'll provide them.

Comment: You need to look at the full headers of the message to see why SpamAssassin scored it like that. You should be able to work out why each rule fired. It may be that you need to do some white listing for messages from the web interface.

Comment: I looked at them. There is nothing more connected with SPAM than I pasted here. 

I took every rule, copied it to Google, found on SpamAssassin wiki - nearly every is connected with presence on blacklist, but when I checked these blacklist - we weren't there... And rDNS is set up correctly, so I don't know why SA fired this rule.

It happens only when I send e-mail from Zimbra's webclient accessed from my smartphone.

If you know how I could get more info about reasons why these rules were applied - I would be grateful to hear :)